# How can I gdb tfcompile by using bazel build?

Tags: tensorflow, gdb, bazel, xla

tfcompile is a binary file to compile an inference graph into executable code for tensorflow XLA which created by bazel build.
If I want to gdb tfcompile file on ubuntu 16.04, it will return message

```
Reading symbols from /PWD/tfcompile...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

It seem that should make bazel compile with something flag like -g?
I have tried to use

```
bazel build XXX --compilation_mode=dbg
```

but there seems not change anything.

How can I resolve this question?

by the way , I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, bazel version 0.8.1 tensorflow r1.0

Thanks for any help!